# What is the difference between city-state markets?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

I've begun playing with the markets in Realm Reborn. The active help says that all markets are connected, so items sold in one city-state can be purchased from another.

So basically it's a global pool? And the **only** difference between markets is the tax fee paid depending on the city the item was sold at? I couldn't help but notice that I have never seen a tax different from 5%. When and how do such taxes change?

Comment: I've seen the tax rates move a few times, but it was during the first month of the game, when there was large city imbalances due to people starting in certain cities to quickly try out certain jobs without needing to grind upto airship/aetheryte access (mostly in LL, because of scholar, since legacy people didnt have that at cap yet)

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that when a buyer standing at market board in a city-state purchases items from a retainer that is stationed in a different city-state (as noted by the nation icon on the market listing), the purchase price will be slightly higher to account for an additional "delivery fee." For example, if a buyer in Ul'dah purchases an item from a retainer stationed in Gridania, an additional fee will be added to the purchase price of the item.

As far as I know, the amount of tax incurred by the seller will be the same regardless of which nation the item is purchased from. I don't recall offhand whether the "delivery fee" is simply removed from the economy, or if it goes to the seller. (If I had to guess, I'd choose the former.)

Comment: Tax rates can differ from city to city, but I have no idea what drives them to move up or down.  (They're not fixed like in XI.)

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand it is that the default tax rate is 5% for buyers, and 5% for sellers.

If the buyer is in the same city as the retainer, the tax rate is lower (possibly zero).

There is a way to get a reduced tax rate as the seller, I think you need to talk to the retainer NPC to see if there is a tax reduction in any of the cities, and you can also move your retainer to a new city at the same NPC.

Answer (score -1):

There is essentially no functional difference in using the market system while your character is physically in any of the three cities. To answer your question, yes, it is essentially a global pool.

The "tax rate" calculation you mention is affected by where your retainer is deployed to. So, if your retainer is deployed to Ul'Dah, you will sell items with the Ul'Dah tax rate, regardless if you summon your retainer from Limsa Lominsa, Gridania, or Ul'Dah.

When you visit a Market Board, you can buy items from retainers dispatched to any of the locations, and your price will be the same. If I summon my retainer in Limsa Lominsa, and he is dispatched to Ul'Dah, and you access the Market Board in Gridania, it all "just works."

Comment: This is false. Purchasing items via the Market Board from a retainer stationed in a city that you are not currently standing in will incur an additional fee. This can easily be verified by walking to any Market Board and comparing the purchase dialog that appears when purchasing from a local retainer vs. a retainer stationed abroad; the latter will specify additional cost. As the fee is a percentage of the sale price, teleporting to the retainer's city can realize significant cost savings when purchasing expensive items.